# What bullets and arrows in Terraria can penetrate enemies?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, Jester Arrows can pierce/penetrate enemies. Which other arrows and bullets can do this? Are there any midgame ones for hardmode crowd control, or can you only do this early-on?

Comment: Why you're getting downvotes doesn't belong in the question.  Also, asking why you're getting downvotes usually means you just get more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the already mentioned Jester Arrow, your options for piercing arrows are [Unholy Arrow](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Unholy_Arrow)(early/midgame), [Chlorophyte Arrow](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_Arrow)(hardmode) and [Luminite Arrow](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Luminite_Arrow)(hardmode).

For bullets you could use [Meteor Shot](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteor_Shot)(midgame) or [Luminite Bullet](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Luminite_Bullet)(hardmode). There is also [Candy Corn](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Candy_Corn)(hardmode) that can be used with the [Candy Corn Rifle](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Candy_Corn_Rifle).

Comment: There are more ammunition-based weapons with piercing/penetrating property: [Helwing Bow](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellwing_Bow), [Shadowflame Bow](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadowflame_Bow), [Pulse Bow](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pulse_Bow), [Bee Knees](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Bee%27s_Knees), [Stake Launcher](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stake_Launcher) (stakes), [Flame Thrower](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Flamethrower) (gel), [Dart Pistol](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dart_Pistol) (darts), [Flare Gun](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Flare_Gun) (flares).

Comment: Note that the amount of enemies each ammo/weapon can pierce may vary from as low as Meteor Shot which can only pierce 1 target. For early hardmode you consider a Blowgun with Crystal Darts. Which gives some auto targeting and up to 7 hits per shot. Damage is decent even later into hardmode and you can replace your Blowgun with Dart Pistol/Rifle.